# Acesso exclusivo a uma Tabela no firebird Tem Como?

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-10

Teria Como Abrir uma Tabela em modo *Exclusivo* no **Firebird** pelo **Delphi** impedindo que outros usuários abrissem a Tabela?

Eu utilizo *Delphi 10.1* e *FireDac* para conexão com a base de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu Consegui fazer assim:

```
// Eu desativei o "AutoCommit" pois sem desativar não Funciona.
DM.TFDConnection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;
DM.TFDQuery.Close;
DM.TFDQuery.SQL.Clear;
// Trava a Linha da tabela com essa SQL
vSql := 'SELECT * FROM TABELA '+
        'WHERE FIELD1 = FIELD1 WITH LOCK';
DM.TFDQuery.SQL.Add(vSql);
DM.TFDQuery.Open;
{ Aqui você faz o que tem que fazer antes de Desbloquear}
  Depois destarva Com "COMMIT" ou "ROLLBACK"
DM.TFDConnection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := True;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não testei se  `DM.TFDConnection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := True;` destrava a tabela.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui para ver como vai ficar.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisara ter um bom controle transacional para ter sucesso com este tipo de tratamento.

Use o `with lock` e será efetuado um bloqueio nos dados da tabela, prevenindo alterações ou exclusões dos dados selecionados!

Ex:

Bloqueio de um registro:
`SELECT * FROM CLIENTES WHERE CODIGO = 255 WITH LOCK`
dessa forma o Cliente do código 255 estará bloqueado para alterações/exclusões.

Para a tabela inteira não use filtros.

Fonte: [Firebird.Org](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-notes-withlock.html)

Comment: beleza entende... Mais como seria eu um `TFDtable`?
tipo `tbUsuarios.open` só que em modo Exclusivo boqueado toda a tabela...

Comment: Este open executara uma consulta SQL certo? Se for o caso.... adicione o `with lock`

Comment: Não.
Isso é uma Componente `TFDTable` do FireDac

Comment: o `TFDTable ` possui a opção `Exclusive` que é uma booleana, e possui ainda opção equivalente na propriedade `UpdateOption`.

Comment: eu Nunca fiz isso sou novato em Delphi ... teria como testar se o registro está mesmo bloqueado?